# Which one is correct in formal style? Why?

Tags: grammar, possessives, demonstratives

1)  It's a habit of mine.

2)  He’s a brother of Maria’s.

3) My salary is higher than that of Joe.

4) My salary is higher than that of Joe's

5) My salary is higher than that of theirs.

6) My salary is higher than that of them.

My question: Numbers 1 and 2 are correct. Based on these two, number 4 should be correct as well, but Cambridge grammar says it's incorrect and we should use number 3 instead. Why is that? What about numbers 5 and 6?

Comment: Number 2 is quite wrong unless it's stipulated that he's a brother of Maria's friend/boss/neighbour. Using "of" *and* a posessive apostrophe is odd. Start from that assumption.

Comment: 2) He's a brother of Maria. (He is Maria's brother). 4) My salary is higher than that of Joe, or, ...higher than Joe's.5) My salary is higher than theirs, or, ...higher than that of them.

Comment: "He's a brother of Maria's" implies that Maria has, or may have, several brothers and he is one of them. Joe (presumably) does not have several salaries. If the speaker knows that Maria has only one brother, they would say "He's the brother of Maria."